Does this look like a quality built multi-swtich power supply unit?
So I just purchased a 50 dollar power supply unit that will run my home theater (important audio equipment) I plan to use all 10 outlets pulling roughly 750 watts of total power. its rated for 15a 1600+ I believe. I plan to then take the main power cord of this unit and plug it into another what i consider "better quality" power supply which is a Furman power supply. No additional units will be plugged into the Furman as to not overload anything Just directly out of this 10 switch power supply into the Furman and from the Furman directly into the wall. This may be redundant and not necessary but I just trust my Furman protection as opposed to anything else.
2 Questions - Is this a bad thing to do and if so why? Also, based on looks does this appear to be a quality built power supply.
As you can tell I'm not wiz on electrical.
FURMAN SPECS
Spike Protection Modes
Line to Neutral
Energy Dissipation
150 joules
Peak Impulse Current
12,000 amps
Maximum Continuous Operating Voltage
130 VAC RMS
Line Voltage
120 (Volts)
Number of Outlets
9
Number of Isolated Banks
0
Outlet Descriptions
All 9 outlets filtered and surge protected
Rack Mountable
Yes
Rack Ears Included
Yes
Front Panel Meter(s)
Digital Voltmeter
Front Media Light(s)
Two 120V incandescent bulbs, 4 watts each
Control
Front panel On/Off switch, Light dimmer knob
Voltage Regulation
No
Compliance
cTUVus
USB Charging
N/A
Low Voltage Trigger
N/A
AC Power Cord
6 ft. captive, 14 AWG, with 3-conductor Edison Plug
Dimensions
19″ W x 7.5″ D x 1.75″ H
Weight
6 lbs
AC Protection Technology
Standard spike and surge protection
Under-Voltage Shutoff
N/A
Maximum Current Rating
15 Amps
Filtration Technology
Standard Level RFI/EMI Filtration
Filtration Rating
Greater than 26dB, 200Khz to 10 Mhz
Signal Line Protection
No
UPC
654061027959
Construction
Steel Chassis, Black Painted
Proposition 65 Warning
WARNING: Cancer and Reproductive Harm
VEVOR 10 OUTLET SPECS
1U Rack Power Strip: Fits 19-inch racks perfectly, keeping your setup organized. Includes screws for easy installation!
15A High Capacity: 15A High Rated Current: Equipped with thickened copper wire cores, it offers excellent conductivity. This power strip supports more devices or higher power devices to operate simultaneously, ensuring a stable power supply. (Do not use receptacle for connecting devices over 15A)
Convenient 10 Outlets: The PDU's 10 NEMA 5-15P outlets can power multiple devices. Each outlet has its switch, so you can turn devices on or off individually as needed, reducing energy waste from devices left on standby without affecting the operation of other devices.
Reliable Power Control: This PDU offers overload, surge, and lightning protection! The built-in surge protector with a 1800J rating absorbs and disperses sudden voltage spikes, while the external resettable breaker quickly cuts power in case of overloads or short circuits, ensuring smooth operation for your valuable equipment.
Durable Material: The power strip’s reinforced metal casing is tough and fire-resistant, offering solid protection. The 6FT power cord (14/3 AWG) is built to handle light pulls and provides flexibility.
enter image description here








Does it have an electrical lab label with UL, ETL, CSA on it?

Is the "Furman" a surge arrestor and/or online battery?  Please elaborate.

@RobertChapin --I just added pictures of the specs on the power supply and the model of Furman I'm using as well as the specs of each in the body of the description

@crip659 Just added a picture of the label and description.

I’m voting to close this question because it is not about home improvement and is better suited for electrical engineering.

@RMDman I apologize! As you can see im new here so I guess I didnt realize the intent was only related to home projects. Does it count that its improving a room in my home lol.

@Random Guy,  No worries, I would move it to electrical, but I have no idea how.  The fact that it's about something in a room improving the house is no more relevant than me asking about an issue with my car because it's in my garage.  You get the point.

@RMDman lol well stated! I will fix that going forward! Thank you.

By the way, for clarity: what you have is generally described as a power distribution unit, not a power supply unit. The latter term is generally reserved for devices which produce a different output than what is fed into them. Devices which are intended to just clean up what is passed into them, filtering and correcting for brownouts, may be referred to as power conditioning units; a UPS is arguably a kind of PCU. (Or at least that's how I have heard the terms used both professionally and in my avocation as a sound engineer, which is where I've usually seen PDUs.)

@RMDman  I've seen a few posts where you recommend moving a post to electrical engineering.  I've noticed they are notorious for bouncing stuff like this back to us.  they don't seem to do a lot of practical stuff.   How's the rebuilds going?

Usually with electrical devices, you want to limit connection points.  Using the furman and velvor you add an extra connection point/plug, using three points instead of two, using either the furman or velvor by itself.

@Jack,  It's going slow. I'm just getting materials delivered for the worst home on monday.  I did get the others dried in and only needing cosmetics.  Thanks for asking.

Based on what I can find in the manufacturers' websites, theses are non-certified use-at-your-own-risk parts from China.
The Furman unit, despite its $300 price tag and "power conditioner" label, doesn't even have a voltage regulator.  It's just a rackmount power strip.
The Vevor site doesn't offer instructions.  If it did, I would expect it to contain a statement similar to the one provided by Furman:
"This equipment shall be connected to a 20 Ampere rated receptacle of the branch circuit."
This instruction reflects the fact that the unit is designed as a power tap, and is definitely not designed for chaining multiple units together.  It also means extension cords are not approved for use in combination with the provided cord.  This contrasts certain small appliances which specify a maximum extension length allowance.
The 20-Amp requirement appears to be a dodge for the derating rules normally applied to 15-Amp circuits.
As for the photos, that's an opinion based topic and I wouldn't offer any guess about the quality.

Hello, Thank you for you reply. I'm looking at the instructions and i dont know if this is what you were referencing but it says. Do not use extension cord(s) to connect the unit. It also says Do not use receptacle for connecting devices over 15a. This device compiles with the Part 15 of the FCC rules. Additionally, Yes, I know this a cheap unit hence why i felt comfortable connecting it to the Furman because the Furman is "suppose" to contain power filtering enhancements that can help with sound. I can say i trust this unit as I have had it for 10 years.

Unfortunately, I cannot find a unit that is HIGH in quality that has 10 outlets with individuals switches to power individuals units at will.

@RandomGuy That's because high quality PDUs are either not switched or have managed switching.  Most folks who rack equipment don't want to accidentally bump into a power switch.

I see nothing obviously wrong. Furman is a respectable brand, assuming this isn't counterfeit. Being a respectable brand, it should carry one or more of the certifying labels that crip659 mentioned, which should mean that they design was inspected and passed by a competent testing lab.
If you stated what your actual concern was, we might be able to address that.

Thank you for the reply! I did post my concern. I plan on plugging 10 individual pieces of equipment into the VEVOR power supply(cheap 50 bucks) and then taking the main power cord from the VEVOR and plugging into into 1 outlet of my FURMAN power supply with nothing else being plugged into the FURMAN, and plugging the FURMAN directly into the wall. I wanted to know if this is against some type of code or is safe. I will look for the labels that @crip659 mentioned.

Assuming the Vevor is safe and not itself being overloaded, I can't see any reason that this wouldn't be appropriate. The Furman is basically just a fancy power strip.

Thank you very much! I'm paranoid about this kind of stuff so with no OBVIOUS objections that helps. and Yes, The Furman is a glorified power strip. No voltage regulation or anything so I get it. I just trust it more than the VEVOR.
